# Accessing single value from Google sheet in html table

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to push data to an HTML table (TDs have ids) using [tabletop.js](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDIQFjAA&url=https://github.com/jsoma/tabletop&ei=BaoiUfDZBqbg0QHcq4CoBw&usg=AFQjCNFxd0PCIhbJP6TuGqEJbebnbTpMKA&bvm=bv.42553238,d.dmQ). I can pull the entire array in one of the tds, but how do I pull in just one value from the array that the tabletop.js builds?

```
$.each( tabletop.sheets("schools").all(), function(i, name) {
      var One = $('<p> '+ name.one + '</p>');
      One.appendTo("td[id$=roundOne]");
    })
```

This puts every value in the column 'one' [spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/pub?key=0AulEnFPPj4jWdE5PY2liVS1tbXZfVnBJUU9NWE5QcXc&output=html) in one td cell with a roundOne id. I only want the first value in the first roundOne td, then the second value in the second roundOne td etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap your `td` selector in jquery, and then only select the `i`th element. When you select `"td[id$=roundOne]"`, it selects all of the `td`'s with that id.

Here's a working example. http://jsfiddle.net/TshQu/